# Estimating pi with a Monte Carlo method results in a larger value than expected

Tags: python, math, pi

I'm trying to estimate pi by dividing the areas of a square and its embedded circle, but I get ~3.66.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
inCount=0
outCount=0
it=1000000
L=100
for i in range(it):
    xran=rnd.random()*L
    yran=rnd.random()*L
    xc=abs(0.5*L-xran)
    yc=abs(0.5*L-yran)
    r=np.sqrt((xc**2)+(yc**2))
    if r<0.5*L:
        inCount=inCount+1
    if r>0.5*L:
        outCount=outCount+1
    if r==0.5*L:
        inCount=inCount+1
        outCount=outCount+1
pigen=inCount/outCount
print('pi generated: '+np.str(pigen))
```

Comment: Can you add your imports to the code?

Comment: This may not work, but try `math.sqrt()` instead

Comment: Why does `L=100`? Can't you do it with `L=1`?

Answer (score 7):

You have

```
pigen=inCount/outCount
```

which gives the proportion of hits inside to outside the radius.

Note that [pi/(4-pi) = 3.659792...](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pi%2F%284-pi%29) which is what your code is currently estimating.

You need

```
pigen=4*inCount/(inCount+outCount)
```

which will give you four times the proportion of hits inside compared to the total, i.e. `pi`.

---

Also note that your code is currently

```
if r<0.5*L:
    inCount=inCount+1
if r>0.5*L:
    outCount=outCount+1
if r==0.5*L:
    inCount=inCount+1
    outCount=outCount+1
```

which can be simplified with [`elif`/`else`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html). Since `r` cannot be both greater than, and less than, `L`, the second `if` can become an `elif`. Likewise, if `r` is neither less than, or greater than, `L` then it **must** be equal so the third `if` can simply become an `else`.

```
if r<0.5*L:
    inCount=inCount+1
elif r>0.5*L:
    outCount=outCount+1
else:
    inCount=inCount+1
    outCount=outCount+1
```

This will prevent unnecesary comparisons of `r` and `L` in your code.

---

Your final code would then be

```
inCount=0
outCount=0
it=1000000
L=100
for i in range(it):
    xran=rnd.random()*L
    yran=rnd.random()*L
    xc=abs(0.5*L-xran)
    yc=abs(0.5*L-yran)
    r=np.sqrt((xc**2)+(yc**2))
    if r<0.5*L:
        inCount=inCount+1
    elif r>0.5*L:
        outCount=outCount+1
    else:
        inCount=inCount+1
        outCount=outCount+1
pigen=pigen=4*inCount/(inCount+outCount)
print('pi generated: '+np.str(pigen))
```

Comment: This was almost right! I also had forgotten to add a 4.

Comment: Do you mean `4 * ` that?

Comment: Ah, yes - in my haste I forgot that.

Answer (score 1):

```
inCount+outCount = 4*r^2
inCount = pi*r^2
```

So if you need to get pi

```
pigen=inCount/(outCount+inCount)*4
```

Answer (score 0):

Wai Ha Lee was almost right! I also had forgotten to add a 4.

If anyone wants to know how it goes, it's like that (and yes, L can be whatever you want):

```
import numpy as np
import random as rnd
inCount=0
outCount=0
it=1000000
L=100
for i in range(it):
    xran=rnd.random()*L
    yran=rnd.random()*L
    xc=abs(0.5*L-xran)
    yc=abs(0.5*L-yran)
    r=np.sqrt((xc**2)+(yc**2))
    if r<0.5*L:
        inCount=inCount+1
    if r>0.5*L:
        outCount=outCount+1
    if r==0.5*L:
        inCount=inCount+1
        outCount=outCount+1
pigen=4*inCount/(inCount+outCount)
print('pi generat: '+np.str(pigen))
```

Answer (score 0):

`inCount` shows the number of points within a circle of radius `r = L/2` and `outCount` shows the number of points in a square exactly containing that circle, but not in the circle itself.

`inCount` is proportional to `pi * r**2` and `outCount` is proportional to `L**2 - pi * r**2 = (4 - pi) * r**2`. When you take the ratio you get `pi / (4 - pi) = 3.66`.

As Wai Ha Lee pointed out, you need to calculate `4 * inCount / (inCount+outCount) = pi`.